# Random Parse query with multiple factors

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have some kind of result algorithm I need some help to improve.

The `PFQuery` should request a bunch of the most relevant results which is a mix of different factors. This is the three factors:

1. The closest object - found with `[query whereKey:xxx nearGeoPoint:xxx withinKilometers:xxx];`
2. The object with the highest "tScore" - found with `[query orderByDescending:@"tScore"];`
3. The  There's another class which among others includes two "UserId"s in the columns "UserOne" and "UserTwo". Here the "UserTwo" should be equal to the `[PFUser currentUser]["UserId"]`. The "UserOne" should be used for this actual query, like: `[query whereKey:@"UserId" equalTo:theUserOneUserIdFromAnotherQuery];`. But be aware that the class that the algo is calling is not the PFUser class..

Sooo, these different query conditions is not running all on the same time but the out put should be a mix of all the factors. An example could be that I limit the query to 21 results and the output is 7 of the closest objects, 7 of the objects with the highest "tScore" and then 7 of the objects with a UserId that equals a UserOne value in an object where the current user's UserId equals UserTwo..

Could this in any way be possible with only one (or very few) request(s) to Parse like with some kind of inner join or anything like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a single request, you just need to define a cloud function to do all the heavy lifting and return the compiled result. You can't get away from making multiple requests in the cloud function, but each of the requests will complete faster there and you minimise network overhead.